# How to host standalone java application on localNetwork

Tags: java

I am working on java desktop application (swing) which needs to be run in  different computers on same Local Network ( LAN ). But this application need to share one database and each application should be able to insert, update, delete records in the same database.
I have created project in java swing using eclipse id. I had created jar file of project and place in folder of my pc. Then I had done changes in Xampp>>Apache>>config

1 changed the listen port 80 to 5digts port(11420) 
2 DocumentRoot "E:\jj\Lp\kk" 
3 then I had restart apache 
4 In browser when I am typing IP:port. getting something following. 
Name Last modified Size Description kkJTP.jar 2019-05-04 02:07 289K
Apache/2.4.29 Server at IP :Port 11420. After clicking over jar file it is downloading. 
what I want,after clicking over jar instead of download direct ui display. Is it possible? How can I just display UI? Waiting your reply﻿. How this application share one database and each computer should be able to insert, update, delete records in the same database.

Note :Standalone appliction we can run on another system with copy of jar file or direct on browser

Comment: Your question is too broad. You are looking for a normal client-server structure, where you have 1 server and X number of clients talking to the server (which has the database). Read any java tutorial about building a server application you find, maybe even tutorials on topics like "REST api".

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem but we used JavaFX and used that program as Applet.